# Prevent duplicate requests using Node, Express, Ghost, and http-proxy

Tags: node.js, express, http-proxy, ghost-blog

I've setup Ghost using the 'npm install ghost' method and have used the subdirectory method to host it at */blog* on my existing Express server.

```
app.all("/blog*", function(req, res){
  blogProxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://localhost:2368' });
});
```

Everything works fine, however every request is duplicated, which is annoying. This is a single page load of */blog*:

```
GET /blog/ 304 29.521 ms - -
GET /blog/ 304 31.080 ms - -
GET /blog/assets/css/screen.css?v=02ca13e45a 304 7.910 ms - -
GET /blog/public/jquery.js?v=02ca13e45a 304 4.262 ms - -
GET /blog/assets/js/jquery.fitvids.js?v=02ca13e45a 304 4.179 ms - -
GET /blog/assets/js/index.js?v=02ca13e45a 304 2.844 ms - -
GET /blog/assets/css/screen.css?v=02ca13e45a 304 11.546 ms - -
GET /blog/public/jquery.js?v=02ca13e45a 304 11.506 ms - -
GET /blog/assets/js/jquery.fitvids.js?v=02ca13e45a 304 11.655 ms - -
GET /blog/assets/js/index.js?v=02ca13e45a 304 11.786 ms - -
GET /blog/assets/fonts/casper-icons.woff 304 0.954 ms - -
GET /blog/assets/fonts/casper-icons.woff 304 2.180 ms - -
```

I assume this is due to the proxy forwarding requests from the primary port to 2368, which is by design? Any way to avoid this?

It's *possible* that I've got some other app.use action in my server configuration that is causing this, but I haven't been able to identify it.

Comment: Hey James - did you ever figure this out?  I'm troubleshooting the exact same thing (with the same type of subdir configuration) and this appears to be the only mention of the problem I can find.

Comment: There's a bit of code, so I'll reply in an answer..

Answer (score 2):

Looking back, here's what changed that I believe fixed the issue:

Initially I had my Node route that handled all non-blog requests *before* Ghost.

The solution, I believe, was to switch these so the Blog code was executing before `app.get('/*')`:

```
// Frontend Blog
ghost({
  config: __dirname + '/app/frontend/ghost/config.js'
}).then(function (ghostServer) {
  ghostServer.start(parentApp);
});

// Backend App      
app.get('/*', function (req, res, next) {       
  res.sendFile("app.html", {root: __dirname + config.path});        
});
```

Comment: Also, the initial `app.all("/blog*")` code happened at the top of my server config file, above bodyparser.